# Counting and grouping in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, count

I was working on a problem in which I had to write a program that will count the number of each item needed for the chefs to prepare. The items that a customer can order are: salad, hamburger, and water. `salad:[# salad] hamburger:[# hamburger] water:[# water]` for example `If order = "hamburger water hamburger"` then the function returns `"salad:0 hamburger:2 water:1"`

My code is :

```
def ite(order,item):
    v=order.split()
    t=[]
    for salad in v:
        if salad==item:
            t.append(item)
            v.remove(item)
    return len (t)

def item_order(order):
    s=ite(order,'salad')
    h=ite(order,'hamburger')
    w=ite(order,'water')
    x='salad:%s hamburger:%s water:%s' %(s,h,w)
    return x
```

but when we give the input `item_order('water water water')`, my program prints

```
salad:0 hamburger:0 water:2
```

instead of

```
salad:0 hamburger:0 water:3
```

It works fine if there are no two consecutive words. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def item_order(order, items=('salad', 'hamburger', 'water')):
    counter = Counter(order.split())
    return ' '.join(['{}: {}'.format(item, counter.get(item, 0)) for item in items])

print(item_order('water water water'))
print(item_order('water salad, salad'))
print(item_order('water hamburger'))
```

test it:

```
print(item_order('water water water'))
print(item_order('water salad, salad'))
print(item_order('water hamburger'))
```

prints:

```
salad: 0 hamburger: 0 water: 3
salad: 1 hamburger: 0 water: 1
salad: 0 hamburger: 1 water: 1
```

### Explanation

The items are given as default parameter:

```
def item_order(order, items=('salad', 'hamburger', 'water')):
```

This make the function more flexible because you can hand in other items if desired:

```
def item_order(order, items=('salad', 'fruit', 'water')):
```

The use of a tuple is intentional here because mutable default parameters such as a list may cause unintentional side effects. No problem here but could be the vase in general.

After splitting the input string at white spaces into a list, `Counter` will create a new `counter` instance:

```
counter = Counter(order.split())
```

For example:

```
>>> Counter('water water salad'.split())
Counter({'salad': 1, 'water': 2})
```

Finally, a list comprehension helps to create anew string:

```
' '.join(['{}: {}'.format(item, counter.get(item, 0)) for item in items])
```

The `' '.join` makes a new string form a list of strings, where the list elements are separated by white space. For example:

```
>>> ' '.join(['abc', 'xyz', 'uvw'])
'abc xyz uvw'
```

The method `get()` of the Python dictionary returns the value for the key if the key is in it, otherwise the default value. For example:

```
>>> d = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
>>> d.get('a', 0)
100
>>> d.get('x', 0)
0
```

Setting this default to `0`, gives a zero count for items not contained in the order:

```
counter.get(item, 0))
```

Finally, the `format()` method helps to put the value for the count in a string. For example:

```
>>> '{}: {}'.format('abc', 10)
'abc: 10'
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do

```
v.remove(salad)
```

Remove that line and it will solve your problem.

```
In [18]: def ite(order,item):
             v=order.split()
             t=[]                        
             for salad in v:
                 if salad==item:
                     t.append(item)
             return len(t)         

In [19]: item_order('salad salad water')
Out[19]: 'salad:2 hamburger:0 water:1'

In [20]: item_order('salad water salad')
Out[20]: 'salad:2 hamburger:0 water:1'

In [21]: item_order('salad water hamburger')
Out[21]: 'salad:1 hamburger:1 water:1'
```

Reason why it wouldn't work for back to back duplicate elements is, in Python, iterating over a sequence does not implicitly make a copy of the list. The list will be modified. You can make the duplicate copy by v[:],

```
In [98]: def ite(order,item):
    v=order.split()
    t=[]
    for salad in v[:]:
        if salad==item:
            t.append(item)
            v.remove(item)
    return len(t)
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained *why* it's not a good idea to remove it.

Comment: @siddharthyadav Now I cannot find the exact quote in the documentation, but the golden rule is: unless *explicitly* stated in the documentation, **never** remove an element while iterating something

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use t.remove() while iterating on it. But why?
I tried to simulate your problem

```
t = ['a', 'b', 'c']
it = iter(it)  # for loop internally use iter() to iterate
it.next()      # it should print 1st element of list which is 'a'
t.remove('a')  #Now list t becomes ['b', 'c']
it.next()      # it should print 2nd element of list which is 'c'
t.remove('b')  #Now list t becomes ['c']
it.next()      #it should print 3rd element of list, But list has only one element
# It throws exception - "StopIteration"
```

This exception is handled by "for" loop silently, so "for" loop won't iterate on 3rd element.

Comment: This actually is the only answer that explains why the OP's code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Altering a list while iterating over it is generally a bad idea - i.e. have you removed an item python has already iterated over or not?

The list object has a count method that may help!

```
split_order = order.split(" ")
salads = split_order.count('salad')
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Although this works fine, you would have to do a `order.count('something')` for every item to check, which implies iterating the whole list `N` times, one per item type (not very efficient).

Comment: Agree completely (it isn't more efficient than the original question), however how big a restaurant are we talking about here?!

Either the Counter solution or using defaultdict (with int initialiser)  would be more efficient.  [https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict]